Query regarding python locking
Say I have N processes opening a json file and writing to it like such-
with open(thefile, ‘w’) as jsonfile:
    json.dump(somedata, jsonfile)

If i want to lock this file so no process reads garbage data, should i lock the file ( by using multiprocessing.Lock) or lock this as the critical section- lock=Lock() with lock: …same code as before
Also what’s the difference?
Basically what I want is that if even one process is reaching that section of the code, no other process should be able to run that part of the code until the lock is released.
Currently my implementation is like such-
import blah blah
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def some_method(parameters):

    with lock:
        with open(json_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict) and value.get("path") == values["path"]:
                try:
                    value["questions"] = new_questions
                except Exception as e:
                    raise Exception("Value is", value, "\n", f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
                break
        with open(json_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as json_file:
            json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4)

with Pool(5) as pool:
    rows = []
    results = pool.starmap(some_method, [parameters])
    rows.extend(results)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

This code does not have every variable filled out, but i just wanted to give an idea of what the function is doing (reading and writing to a json, along with a lot more functionality which i havent added to this code). I recieved errors regarding some json issues, and running with one process fixes that, which leads me to believe that there is an issue with the multiprocessing aspect of my code.

Multiprocessing locks only work between processes in the same script. File locks can be used between unrelated processes.

As @Barmar mentioned, Multiprocessing locks only work between processes in the same script. File locks can be used between unrelated processes.Suspected the same. I tried using the FileLock library, seemed to resolve the issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
